# How to set Local Storage path for Android

Tags: android, qt, qml

I try to embed the sqlite file generated by QML's Local Storage for Android. The code below works for desktop. Although There are sqlite and ini files in Android's assets folder, the app doesn't see the database file as default. How can I get it work?

The code in main.cpp:

```
QString customPath = "assets:/OfflineStorage";
QDir dir;
if(dir.mkpath(QString(customPath))){
        qDebug() << "Default path >> "+engine.offlineStoragePath();
        engine.setOfflineStoragePath(QString(customPath));
        qDebug() << "New path >> "+engine.offlineStoragePath();
    }
engine.clearComponentCache();
```

Comment: Try [QStandardPaths](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html) with appropriate [enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum) instead. I can't test it now but sometime it worked for me well.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it as `QStandardPaths::writableLocation( QStandardPaths::StandardLocation::AppLocalDataLocation );` , the new path is `/data/user/0/org.project.myapp/files/OfflineStorage` and the database is in assets/OfflineStorage path. But it still doesn't work. assets folder is files folder in Android system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been solved [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/101061/how-to-set-local-storage-path-for-android-for-sqlite/14). The problem was copying sqlite and ini file to the right location.